# turning off LCD in lock mode in WIndows

Tags: windows, lcd

I have Windows 8 installed.  How can I turn off the monitor when the computer is in lock mode (<kbd>windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)?

I'm using a netbook and I can't turn the display off since there is no power button for that. I'm doing this to try to save power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me in Win7, but not tested in Win8 so far (so that bit's up to you! :)

1. Download [Wizmo](http://www.grc.com/wizmo/wizmo.htm)
2. Create a shortcut to Wizmo.exe (and optionally rename as desired, change the icon, set keyboard shortcut etc.)
3. In the shortcut's properties, add  `monoff lock` to the **Target** field as follows:

   [image]
4. Double-clicking the shortcut should lock the system and turn the monitor off

---

You can also use [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) to achieve the same thing. However, since a single `nircmd monitor off lockws` command does not work, you'll need to first create a batch file containing the following commands, then create a shortcut to the batch file:

> nircmd monitor off
> nircmd lockws

Note: In the download package you'll get 2 EXEs, so you can use the console mode *nircmdc.exe* as well instead of the normal *nircmd.exe*

---

A purpose-built utility for this is the [Monitor Off Utility](http://www.dekisoft.com/mou.php):

[image]