# turning off dell monitor programatically

Tags: windows-8, display

I run windows 8 on a desktop and I want to turn off my dell monitor when my computer sits idle. I tried using the nircmd / "turn off display" option under power but every time when that kicks in I get a "no vga cable" message flowing around on my monitor as opposed to getting it turned off which is annoying and defeating the purpose.

I used the same monitor for another desktop running XP before and I was able to put it to stand by mode without the no cable message (the power button on the monitor changes from green to orange). Any suggestions for doing the same thing on windows 8?

Comment: Can you check whether [Wizmo](http://superuser.com/a/483170/138343) behaves the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open the `power management`( [image: image1]  + <kbd>R</kbd>, and type `powercfg.cpl` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

[image]

Comment: I did that already. When the time is reached the screen went black and a "no vga cable" message starts to flow around rather than shutting off the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, once it says "no VGA cable", it's the monitor's problem at that point and there's probably nothing else you can do from Windows.  Typically, all Windows can do is stop sending the display signal, and that must be how your monitor responds to not getting a signal.

But most monitors I've seen that were made after the 90's will go into power-save after a few minutes of showing a "no input" message.

Also, if you open the monitor's settings menu, you might be able to find a setting somewhere that specifies how long it waits before going into powersave mode, or maybe you can disable the message.