# Turn off displays after certain time at lock screen (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, display, power-management, screensaver, lock

My screensaver is setup to turn on by default after 4 minutes and wake up with a password required, and the displays to turn off after 10 minutes. This works if I don't lock my computer manually, but usually I do. Other people in the house have started complaining that the displays are still on and I just confirmed that they are, at the lock screen, and the displays don't shut off. Google-fu led me to adding "console lock display off timeout" via regedit, which I did, but that doesn't work in Windows 7. https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/8267-power-options-add-console-lock-display-off-timeout.html

If anyone has any ways to get the displays to shut off automatically after 10 minutes (which is my setting for my power plan to turn off the display after) when I specifically lock the computer, rather than having it go into the screensaver automatically, that would be appreciated.

Comment: See also the answer in this question: https://superuser.com/a/483170/168519

Answer (score 0):

Instead of turning the screen off after 10 minutes after locking the computer, how about turning it off immediatly when locking? Since you are locking the computer, it won't be used in a while anyway, might as well turn the screen off from the beginning. At maketecheasier the is an [article](https://www.maketecheasier.com/turn-off-monitor-automatically-lock-windows/) describing two different ways to accomplish this.

1. Use a [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) script, however, this will only work for using the "Win + L" hotkey combination to lock the computer. Install AutoHotKey and make sure to run the script at startup. The script can look like this:

`;; Use Win + L to Lock Your System`

```
#L:: ;; Win + L
{
  Sleep, 200
  DllCall("LockWorkStation")
  Sleep, 200
  SendMessage,0x112,0xF170,2,,Program Manager
}
return
```

2. Install and use [MPowerSaver](http://mpowersaver.in/), which is a small Windows program made for situations like this. It will automatically turn off the display when Windwos is locked.

Comment: The mpowersaver[.]in domain has switched owners, see old version here: http://web.archive.org/web/20180126153945/http://mpowersaver.in/ (but download links do not work there)